# MonoDevelop not recognising MonoBehaviour

Tags: c#, linux, unity-game-engine, monodevelop, linux-mint

I'm using Unity3d & MonoDevelop to develop games on Linux Mint (19.3 Cinnamon, 64-Bit).

However, when i open a C#-Script in MonoDevelop, it won't recognize `MonoBehaviour`.
`MonoBehaviour` is still shown in white color. 
It also won't detect things like `Vector3`.

What i tried yet:

- Reinstall MonoDevelop
- Run MonoDevelop with sudo

Comment: Are you creating the script inside unity3d? Other wise you might miss some references. Share the content of your code file

Comment: yes i create them in unity3d. I add a script example to the original post

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution:

In Unity you have to set "monodevelop" in the directory "usr/bin/" as script-editor, not a shortcut or something else.

Then it works :)